# Period of $f(x-1)+f(x+1)=\sqrt{5}\cdot f(x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, periodic-functions

> Find the period of: $$f(x-1)+f(x+1)=\sqrt{5}\cdot f(x)\ , \forall x\in R$$

I reduced this down to $f(x-2)+f(x+2)=3f(x)$, I can't get rid off that factor $3$, what to do next, please help.

Comment: Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving, $$t^2-\sqrt5 t+1=0$$


$$\implies t_1,t_2=\dfrac{\sqrt5\pm1}2, f(n)=At_1^n+Bt_2^n$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee sir, beside this, also please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723525/solving-vector-equation-employing-products

Comment: Are you sure it's periodic?

Comment: @J.G. I got this problem from AOPS, I know nothing about the problem.

Comment: Find **the** period ? If $T$ is a period, so is $2T$. Do you mean find the smallest period ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes fundamental.

Comment: Without further information/constraints, $f(x)$ does not have to be periodic. For example, $f(x) = \phi^x = e^{x\ln \phi}$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ satisfies the functional equation, and is not periodic.